# Why does it say implicit declaration of function in main? C programming

Tags: c

I am declaring the function with `#define` before it is used in main but I still get:

> implicit declaration of function fakultet...

The answer should be 6 ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define fakultet(x) ((x)>1?((x)*(fakultet(x-1))):(1))

int main(void) {
    printf(fakultet(3));
}
```

Comment: Macros are not recursively expanded.

Comment: Also `printf(fakultet(3));` --> `printf("%d\n", fakultet(3));`

Comment: do not use macros for the functions.

Comment: Side note: Although computing factorials is the *typical* first example for a recursive function, doing this in C isn't the best idea. A simple iterative approach is better: `unsigned fact(unsigned n) { unsigned f = 1; for (unsigned i = n; i > 1; --i) f *= i; return f; }` and of course, there are [much better algorithms](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm)

Comment: Or slightly less readable, but without an extra local variable: `unsigned fact(unsigned n)  { unsigned f = 1; while (n > 1) f *= n--; return f; }`

Answer (score 6):

> I am declaring the function with `#define`

You are actually declaring a macro, not a C function:

```
#define fakultet(x) ((x)>1?((x)*(fakultet(x-1))):(1))
```

Macros are expanded only once. Therefore the when you use `fakultet` in your code:

```
printf(fakultet(3));
```

is expanded to:

```
printf(((3)>1?((3)*(fakultet(3-1))):(1)));
```

and the compiler does not find a C function with named `fakultet()`. Therefore you get:

> implicit declaration of function fakultet...